# Can't make module export work for express router

Tags: node.js, express

I am really struggling to separate my routes into different files.  In my ./routes/index.js file, I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

...

router.all('/', requireLogin, function(req, res, next){
next();
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

res.render('index', { title: appConfig.appTitle, 
                  messageForm: req.session.messageData,
                  });
});


router.get('/login', function(req, res){
res.render('login', {title: appConfig.appTitle,
                     messageForm: passport.messageData})
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
failureRedirect: '/login',
successRedirect: '/', 
failureFlash: true }
));

router.use('./inventory', require('./inventory'))
router.use('./transaction', require('./transaction'))

module.exports = router;
```

now, the /login page and the / page is working properly.  However, when I try to go to /transaction, I am getting an error saying cannot GET /transaction.  Here's the code in transaction.js which resides at the same directory as index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

console.log('router.get');
});


module.exports = router;
```

But if I include the router.get('/') from transaction.js into index.js and rename it to router.get('/transaction'), it is working correctly.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Try removing the dot in front of the slash. If that doesnt work try adding  in the app.js file like this `app.use('/transaction', require('./transaction'))`

Comment: tried removing the dot on the url but I still got the same error.  I also tried inserting app.use('/transaction', require('/routes/transaction')) but still no luck.  could this be a bug in my setup?  Also, not sure if it's related but I'm getting "cannot GET /transaction?" which has a question mark at the end.  Here's the text from the general section of the header if I do an inspect element:  Request     URL:http://localhost:3000/transaction?
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:404 Not Found
    Remote Address:[::1]:3000

Comment: ok, it worked!  I just removed the dot in the URL.  the problem was I made some changes in the transaction.js.  silly me!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.Just remove dot in urls .

```
router.use('/inventory', require('./inventory'))
router.use('/transaction', require('./transaction'))
```

Comment: this worked.  sorry for the previous comment.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in app.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index'),
    transaction = require('./routes/transaction');

app.use('/transaction', transaction);
app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: i think this worked as well after I removed the dot in the url.